# res.download() throw Request aborted

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express and trying to download a file, then load the page. I understood that the problem is stopping res.download with res.render but I can' t figure out how to resolve this. I also tried to put res.render() inside the callback function of res.download(), the only thing that happen is that res.render stopped working but the file would download.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.download(
    "./public/sample-zip/Lost Sky - Dreams.zip",
    "Lost Sky - Dreams.zip",
    err => {
      if (err) console.log("Errore nel dw: " + err);
    }
  );

  res.render("index");
});
```

Comment: Page redirection after a download should be done by the client, not the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't end the same request in multiple ways - `download` behind the scenes will call `sendFile` which sends a file to the client and ends the request, similarly `render` will send page content and also end the request.

The correct approach here is to allow the file to be downloaded to the client and then have the client redirect the page on the back of a successful download.

Comment: Sorry if it seems a dumb question, but how do I do it?

Comment: @TommasoGiubilel on the client you can set `window.location` to redirect the page